# Jinja2 templates inheritance

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

With Jinja2, do all blocks need to be defined in the base template from which all other templates extend? For instance, given the following templates:

```
<-- ultra_base.j2 -->
<head> 
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  {% block extra_js %} {% endblock %}
</body>
```

and

```
<-- child.j2 -->
{% extends ultra_base %}

{% block extra_js %}
  <script src="somefile.js"> 
{% endblock %}

{% block page_js %} {% endblock %}
```

and

```
<-- grandchild.j2 -->
{% extends child %}

{% block content %} 
<h2> Grandchild Content </h2>
{% endblock content %} 

{% block page_js %}
<script src="grandchild.js"></script>
{% endblock page_js %}
```

The `page_js` block is never rendered. Is there some way to render it without changing `ultra_base`?

Answer (score 2):

You could render `page_js` by putting the `{% block page_js %} {% endblock %}` inside the `extra_js` block in `child.j2`:

```
<-- child.j2 -->
{% extends ultra_base %}

{% block extra_js %}
    <script src="somefile.js"> 
    {% block page_js %} 
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think this preserves the order of content you are after?

Comment: Yeah I think so. I'm just trying to avoid changing ultra_base template, its actually in another repo.

Comment: In that case, it is probably best to think of your `child.j2` template as a base template, but wrap the entire contents in `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `page_js` block in `child.j2` is "in the middle of nowhere", it does not alter any block of the `ulta_base.j2`, so Jinja2 will not render anything from it. The solution is quite simple, you don't even need to define a new `extra_js` block, just use Jinja2's [super()](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#super-blocks) function:

`ultra_base.j2` remains the same:

```
<!-- ultra_base.j2 -->
<head> 
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  {% block extra_js %} {% endblock %}
</body>
```

the `child.j2` template:

```
<!-- child.j2 -->
{% extends ultra_base %}

{% block extra_js %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script src="somefile.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and the `grandchildj2`:

```
<!-- grandchild.j2 -->
{% extends child %}

{% block content %} 
<h2> Grandchild Content </h2>
{% endblock content %} 

{% block extra_js %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script src="grandchild.js"></script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
```

Jinja2 will take care of including block contents from the parent templates.